# adding a Q3DScatter to an existing QDialog form

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I would like to insert a `Q3DScatter` instance onto one of my forms. I am able to construct the graph and display it with:

```
Q3DScatter *graph = new Q3DScatter();
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);

...do some graph stuff...

container.show()
```

This successfully creates the graph and shows it in its own window/container. I would now like to place it inside another form that has been designed in `qt-creator`. I have placed an empty `widget` on the form(QDialog) as a placeholder, but am unable to move the `Q3DScatter` into the widget.

I see `Q3DScatter::Q3DScatter(const QSurfaceFormat *format = Q_NULLPTR, QWindow *parent = Q_NULLPTR)` in the documentation but I dont have a QWindow parent to attach it to, as the form I would like to add it to is a QDialog...

I am very new to `widgets` in general, so please correct me if this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

Add the container as a child of the dialog. Put in a layout if you need to resize when the dialog is resized. Example:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(Q3DScatter *scatter, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QHBoxLayout * const l = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    l->setMargin(0);
    l->addWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(scatter, this);
}
```